# Wordpress _s:theme get_post_thumbnail wrong size

Tags: php, wordpress

*(using underscores-frame for wordpress)*

I have a conditional header like this:

```
<header id="my_id" class="my_class" style='background-image: url(
 <?php if (is_single() && has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {
 echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'big-thumb' );} 
else { header_image(); }?>)'>
```

Everything is working correctly, except that the code is not grabbing the correct thumb-size. I have defined sizes in functions.php like this:

```
add_image_size('big-thumb', 1200, 500, true);
```

The 1200-500 image-file exists and has been resized and cropped correctly by functions.php

But the outputted image is not *my_image-1200-500.jpg* but rather *my_image-150-150.jpg*

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe use *wp_get_attachment_image_scr* instead of *wp_get_attachment_thumb_url* ? But when i try im not getting anything..

Comment: I've tried doing this; *wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'big-thumb');* But HTML-output then says: *background-image: url(Array)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
<header id="my_id" class="my_class" style='background-image: url(
<?php if (is_single() && has_post_thumbnail($post_id)) {

echo wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'big-thumb') [0];} 

else { header_image(); }?>)'>
```